# How to position Django help_text between Label & Input instead of under Input?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a custom form where each field is added as a widget, i.e.
`widgets = { "title": forms.TextInput( attrs={"class": "review-input review-title"}, ), }`

I also added help_texts in the Meta class of this form i.e.

`help_texts = { "title": "Help text title", }`

By default, this puts the help text below the input tag.

[image]

However, I want to place the help text between label & input. The form is generated as {{ form.as_p }} inside a flex-box.

Could you please help with that?

I already tried to style the generated  help text, but it messed the whole form/layout. It would help to have it generated in the right place from the start.